# Can I use a bootable drive partition to install OS on another partition on the same SSD?

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-systems, boot-partition

I realize this is a little out of the box question so I wanted to reach out to the experts on the matter.

I have a 256GB SSD. I have 2 partitions on it. Partition 1 is 20GB, another one is the rest of the drive. I have created a Windows 10 bootable "disk" on partition 1:

Now, I want to install Windows 10 using partition 1 bootable "disk" on to partition. I would like to know if this is possible? Or if there's a way to make this work.

Comment: What is there exactly on partition 1?

Comment: Partition 1 has Windows 10 bootable disk. One can install an OS using that partition. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Possible? Probably, I've not done exactly that but similar. You may have issues with the boot records. If the drive is empty other than your install media, give it a go?

Comment: Actually, there are likely *more* than two partitions -- in particular, there's a partition with EFI info for booting that points to where the OS resides. You'd need to modify that to point to the *new* OS partition.

Comment: @NickSlash - I did give it a try. It said "You cannot install an OS connected via USB or port 1394".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Your "bootable" partition is irrelevant for your case,...on your "rest of drive" partition, if you have OS installed, you have 2 solutions; -freeup some space from that partition and install next os onto it(you need 45gb of hdd, it might work at 25gb minimum, but will have issues on updates, eventually). -while in that OS, create VHDx drive, mount, and initiate setup while on that OS to that virtual drive(you will loose around 20-30% of speed on VHDx, but itll be one file that can be easily moved from drive to drive and booted from, depends what you need).

Comment: I think there's a little confusion. On the entire drive, there are 2 partitions. One partition has the Windows 10 installer (not ISO, but installable media similar to USB drive). Partition 2 has nothing on it. I want to use partition 1 media to install Windows 10 on partition 2.

Comment: "You cannot install an OS connected via USB or port 1394" ... how did you create that partition 1? recreate it using diskpart, same copy, all the same,...it has to work, been working for me since vista, just replicate commands for your disk; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/install/create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive ,...and edit part where u need size for first partition "create partition primary size=20480".

Answer (score 0):

While booting from one partition, you cannot install Windows on another
partition.

The only solution would be to format partition 2 and copy to it the
contents of the entire partition 1. However, copying the running system
presents some technical problems for cloning which are not solved in
Windows. You will need a third-party product for that.

You could use for example
[EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/clone-system-partition-free.html)
for cloning (refuse any offered bundled software installation),
and there are
[alternative products](https://alternativeto.net/software/easeus-partition-manager/?platform=windows&license=free).

Comment: Thank you for the response but I think there is a slight misunderstanding here. Partition 1 doesn't have a functional Win 10 OS. It is simply the installer partition (meaning it only has the content to install an actual functioning OS). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean that you have booted into the Windows installation media and stopped after the first phase of the installation into partition 1? Or that you have stored the installation ISO in that partition?

Comment: I have the installation ISO on partition 1 and I was to use that ISO to install the OS on partition 2.

Comment: You can't, since you need to boot this ISO, and then the ISO is closed. You need to create a bootable USB from that ISO. And then the 20GB becomes just lost space.

Comment: I have partition 1 as a bootable disk. And that's what I am using as an installer to install Win 10 on partition 2.

Comment: You can even install OS onto that bootable partition, tho size of 20Gb will be an issue. But from my understanding you do not want this. You want 1 bootable partition and 2nd partition to install OS(s) to? Keep in mind that GPT boot and MBR boot aint the same, you want MBR for your action(GPT wont give you the menu to pick what to "boot")